# Find location of mobile

Tags: android

I want to find latitude & longitude when I enter the mobile number.

There is any way to do that in android?

Answer (score 3):

No.

*Impractical* exceptions to the above answer.

- You are a telecommunication company, then you can do triangulation between the phone and the nearby cell towers.
- You are law enforcement, then ask the telecommunication company (will usually need subpoena).
- You find a way to hack the phone remotely (e.g. using booby trapped webpage), and then turn on it's GPS and get it to send back an answer.