# How to get map view location using mobile number

Tags: android

Is it possible to create android app to find map location using Mobile Number. As soon as the mobile number is entered the app prompts the user of that mobile number to allow access for finding his location.

If yes please suggest the possible ways of creating apps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may get some clue from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387354/find-location-of-mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get exact location from mobile number, because it is subject to mobile security that harm the government policy.

But you can get state name from mobile number, as i have seen on website so that using a web service and some another way we can access that data. Just check out this [link](http://trace.bharatiyamobile.com/).

Comment: ya but i want to know the users location with his permission.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of access you can ask from just a mobile number? Ofcourse you can make a call to user's mobile by asking him/her for that, and then further more you can ask user to speak his/her location which you can parse at your end. Other than this I am not able imagine any permission. Also as @milind pointed out, you can guess few things like network provider and area from the mobile number, as they are allocated in a pattern. There are few vendors who provide this API as a service, one of them is [Mobile Number Tracker](http://www.mobilenumbertracker.com).